# Updating and saving an activerecord field in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, race-condition

There is a simple method:

```
def get_award(user)
  u = User.find(user).score += 10
  u.save
end
```

My problem is, is there a potential race condition cause a user `get_award` twice but get only 10 score? How to avoid it?

Comment: Updating is not proper.. typo ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the 'user' instance, update the score and save it. In your code you're saving the class, not the instantiated object:

```
def get_award(user)
  u = User.find(user).score += 10
  u.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

related questions : [How do I avoid a race condition in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037029/how-do-i-avoid-a-race-condition-in-my-rails-app)

You can use two kinds of locking optimistic & pessimistic

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
See point No 10