# Race conditions in Rails first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to enforce uniqueness of values in one of my table fields. Changing the table isn't an option. I need to use ActiveRecord to conditionally insert a row into the table but I'm concerned about synchronization.

Does `first_or_create` in Rails ActiveRecord prevent race conditions?

This is the source code for `first_or_create` from GitHub:

```
def first_or_create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
  first || create(attributes, options, &block)
end
```

Is it possible that a duplicate entry will result in the database due to synchronization issues with multiple processes?

Comment: AR is full of race conditions like this.

Comment: See (SO dup) [How do I avoid a race condition in my Rails app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037029/how-do-i-avoid-a-race-condition-in-my-rails-app) and Rails Cookbook [Avoiding Race Conditions with Optimistic Locking](http://underpop.free.fr/r/ruby-on-rails/cookbook/I_0596527314_CHP_3_SECT_19.html)

Comment: @dbenhur - I can't use optimistic locking because it involves adding a field to the table. One of my conditions was that I can't add a field so its not a duplicate.

Comment: If you can't use optimistic locking, you can try explicit pessimistic locks (though that will hurt performance), or you can add constraints in the db, and catch constraint violations, and retry with appropriate semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can significantly reduce the chance of conflict with either [optimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) or [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html). Of course optimistic locking requires adding a field to the table, and pessimistic locking doesn't scale as well--plus, it depends on your data store's capabilities.

I'm not sure whether you need the extra protection, but it's available.

Comment: I couldn't use optimistic locking because modifying the table wasn't an option. The issue with pessimistic locking was that I couldn't specify the lock isolation level I needed through Rails without inserting InnoDB-specific syntax. I ended up just using `first_or_create` despite the possibility of duplicate rows.

Though I think I could have used the validation helpers in ActiveRecord to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: They suffer from the same race condition

Answer (score 28):

The Rails 4 [documentation for `find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) provides a tip that may be useful for this situation:

> Please note *this method is not atomic*, it runs first a SELECT, and if there are no results an INSERT is attempted. If there are other threads or processes there is a race condition between both calls and it could be the case that you end up with two similar records.
>
> Whether that is a problem or not depends on the logic of the application, but in the particular case in which rows have a UNIQUE constraint an exception may be raised, just retry:
>
> ```
> begin
>   CreditAccount.find_or_create_by(user_id: user.id)
> rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
>   retry
> end
> ```

Similar error catching may be useful for Rails 3. (Not sure if the same `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error is thrown in Rails 3, so your implementation may need to be different.)

Comment: Just for the record: Rails 3 throws an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` (what is not very specific).

Comment: Bummer. So you could still potentially do a `rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` in order to retry, even if it doesn't read as well as in Rails 4?

Comment: You could. But the problem is that `StatementInvalid` include also invalid SQL, `NULL` in non-null columns and so on. You might retry thing that will never work. Perhaps you want to use something like https://github.com/nfedyashev/retryable#readme to avoid running into a loop.

Comment: More of a question than an argument... The `retry` would only run once though, wouldn't it? So then if it's bad SQL or whatever, it would hard-fail on the 2nd run.

Comment: No, `retry` would retry the block every time when there was an error in the block before. If you want to avoid running into a loop, you need to count how offen you retried and you must not retry (but raise) if `tries > max_tries`. Look into the `retryable` gem.

Comment: For me `retry` was not an option due an [ActiveRecord QueryCache problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183537/rails-activerecordrecordnotunique-with-first-or-create)

Answer (score 4):

Rails 6 (released in 2019) introduced a new method, [`create_or_find_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create_or_find_by), specifically to deal with the potential race condition / synchronization issue that exists with `first_or_create` and `find_or_create_by`,  where two different threads could simultaneously SELECT to see if the target record exists, both see that it doesn't, and then both try to INSERT it.

Example usage:

```
company = Company.create_or_find_by(name: 'Stack Overflow')
```

(Where `Company` is an existing ActiveRecord model, and `name` is a unique-constrained column on the `company` table.)

Also available: [`create_or_find_by!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-create_or_find_by-21), which raises an exception if a validation error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think first_or_create is atomic. from console i see a select operation, and then, create.
so locking is required.
if u use pasimistic lock, no extra col is required.
use advisory_lock.

```
SomeModel.with_advisory_lock("get_or_create_#{some_key}") do
    SomeModel.where(external_id: external_id).first_or_create
end
```