# Rails: ActiveRecord:RecordNotUnique with first_or_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency

I have this index in my Model's table:

```
UNIQUE KEY `index_panel_user_offer_visits_on_offer_id_and_panel_user_id` (`offer_id`,`panel_user_id`)
```

And this code:

```
def get_offer_visit(offer_id, panel_user_id)
  PanelUserOfferVisit.where(:offer_id => offer_id, :panel_user_id => panel_user_id).first_or_create!
end
```

is randomly causing an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception in our application, 
the issue is:

> Duplicate entry for key
>   'index_panel_user_offer_visits_on_offer_id_and_panel_user_id'

I've read on the rails doc that `first_or_create!` is not an atomic method and can cause this kind of issues in a high concurrency environment and that a solution would be just to catch the exception and retry.

I tried different approaches, including [Retriable gem](https://github.com/kamui/retriable) to retry a certain number of times to repeat the operation but RecordNotUnique is still raised.

I even tried to change the logic:

```
def get_offer_visit(offer_id, panel_user_id)
  begin
    offer_visit = PanelUserOfferVisit.where(:offer_id => offer_id, :panel_user_id => panel_user_id).first_or_initialize
    offer_visit.save!        
    offer_visit

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    offer_visit = PanelUserOfferVisit.where(:offer_id => offer_id, :panel_user_id => panel_user_id).first
    raise Exception.new("offer_visit not found") if offer_visit.nil?

    offer_visit
  end
end
```

But the code still raise the custom exception I made and I really don't understand how it can fails to create the record on the first try because the record exists but then when it tries to find the record it doesn't find it again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be hitting rails query cache for `PanelUserOfferVisit.where(...).first` query: rails have just performed identical SQL query, it thinks that result will remain the same for the duration of the request.

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache` before the second call to db should help

Also you do not have to `save!` the record if it is not `new_record?`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly your problem here is due to a race condition. I didn't found the exact piece of code from Github but lets say the method `find_or_create` is something like (edit: here is [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1a5fdf77122e32fc710148ea3e795fedb597ad46/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L166-L170)):

```
def first_or_create!(attributes = nil, &block)
  first || create!(attributes, &block)
end
```

You should try to solve the race conditions using [optimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) or [pessimistic locking](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html)

Once locking implemented within your custom method, you should continue capturing possible `NotUnique` exceptions but try to clean cache or use `uncached` block before to perform the find again.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue but the root cause was not related to a race condition.

With `first_or_create!`, the INSERT remove surrounding spaces in the value but the SELECT don't.

So if you try this:

```
Users.where(email: 'user@mail.com ')
```

(mind the space at the end of the string), the resulting sql query will be:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@mail.com ' ORDER BY "users"."id";
```

which result in not finding the potentially existing record, then the insert query will be:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("email") VALUES ('user@mail.com');
```

which can result in `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error if a record with 'user@mail.com' as an email already exists.

I do not have enough details about your problem so it might be unrelated but it might helps others.