# Incrementing column in Rails (numbering scheme like Github's repo issues)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can you do a numbering scheme like Github does with repositories issues and pull requests inside a project (`1, 2, 3, ..., n`)?

Assume we have a `Project` model and also have a `Post` model, where `Post belongs_to Project` .

I could imagine looking for the last `Post` for a given project and incrementing that number, but I *think* this could easily lead to a race condition.

Comment: why not just using an `id`?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko perhaps I didn't explain well and relied on Github to do the explaining for me. The idea is that each project has its own specific numbering. That is, Project #1 has `1, 2, 3`, Project #2 has `1, 2, 3` and so on.

With an auto-incrementing `id` you would have Project #1 have `1`, and maybe Project #2 has `2, 3`, and Project #1 has `4, 5, 6`.

This would be a loss of continuity for the user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have..

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

One possible solution is to add a has_many in your Project model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

and use the size property

proj = Project.find( ... )

proj.posts.**size**

Comment: How does this overcome the race condition issue?

Comment: I guess you could add unique index on the `post_number` and `project_id`. That should probably fix the race condition.

Comment: This does not solve the race condition. Rails has its own solution for this.
Take a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037029/how-do-i-avoid-a-race-condition-in-my-rails-app